# In Triangle, $\sin\frac A2\!+\!\sin\frac B2\!+\!\sin\frac C2\!-\!1\!=\!4\sin\frac{\pi -A}4\sin\frac{\pi -B}4\sin\frac{\pi-C}4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles

To prove 
$$\sin\frac A 2+\sin\frac B 2+\sin\frac C 2-1=4\sin\frac{\pi -A}4\sin\frac{\pi -B}4\sin\frac{\pi-C}4$$

My approach :

$$
\begin{align}
\text{L.H.S.} & = \sin\frac{A}{2}+\sin \frac{B}{2}+\sin\frac{C}{2} -1 \\[8pt]
& = 2\sin\frac{A+B}{4}\cos\frac{A-B}{4}+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{C}{2}\right)-1 \\[8pt]
& = 2\sin\frac{\pi -C }{4}\cos\frac{A-B}{4} - 2\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi -C}{4} \right) \\[8pt]
& =2\sin\frac{\pi -C }{4}\left\{ \cos\frac{A-B}{4} - \sin\left(\frac{\pi -C}{4} \right)\right\}
\end{align}
$$

Unable to move further please help. thanks.

Comment: Try A=B=C=0.­ See?­­­­

Comment: Are $A$, $B$ and $C$ supposed to be the angles of a triangle?

Comment: I think we've seen essentially this same question here before.  I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Yes, these are angles of triangles already edited.. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$\sin\frac{C}{2}=\cos\frac{A+B}{2}$$
and now use following formulas
$$\sin p+\sin q=2\sin\frac{p+q}2\cos\frac{p-q}2$$
$$\cos p-\cos q=-2\sin\frac{p+q}2\sin\frac{p-q}2$$
to obtain
$$\begin{align}\sin\frac{A}{2}+\sin\frac{B}{2}+\sin\frac{C}{2}&=\sin\frac{A}{2}+\sin\frac{B}{2}+\cos\frac{A+B}{2}\\&=2\sin\frac{A+B}{4}\cos\frac{A-B}{4}+1-2\sin^2\frac{A+B}{4}\\
&=2\sin\frac{A+B}{4}\left(\cos\frac{A-B}{4}-\sin\frac{A+B}{4}\right)+1\\
&=2\sin\frac{A+B}{4}\left(\cos\frac{A-B}{4}-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2-\frac{A+B}{4}\right)\right)+1\\
&=4\sin\frac{\pi-A}4\sin\frac{\pi-B}4\sin\frac{\pi-C}4+1\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

I will prove,

$$\sin\frac{A}{2}+\sin \frac{B}{2}+\sin\frac{C}{2} - \sin \frac{\pi}{2}= 4\sin \frac{\pi -A}{4}\sin\frac{\pi -B}{4} \sin\frac{\pi-C}{4}$$

Let $z_1=e^{iA/2}$, $z_2=e^{iB/2}$, $z_3 = e^{iC/2}$, $z_4=e^{i\pi/2}=i$

If $z_0=e^{i\theta}$, $\sin(\theta)= \frac1{2i}\left(z_0 - \frac1{z_0}\right)$

Therefore, LHS,

$$\frac{1}{2i}\left(z_1-\frac{1}{z_1}+z_2-\frac{1}{z_2}+z_3-\frac{1}{z_3} -z_4+\frac{1}{z_4}\right)$$

Substituting, $z_4=i$,

$$\frac{1}{2i}\left(z_1-\frac{1}{z_1}+z_2-\frac{1}{z_2}+z_3-\frac{1}{z_3} -2i\right)$$

---

Now for the RHS,

$\sin\left(\frac{\pi-A}{4}\right) = \sin((\pi/2-A/2)/2) = \frac{1}{2i}(t-\frac{1}{t})$ where $t=\sqrt{\frac{z_4}{z_1}}$

Similarly for the other two terms. Multiply and we are done.

Comment: That's why I love complex numbers.

Comment: @Awesome "complex" is such a misnomer. Should be simple numbers. :D

Comment: Yep... They make everything simpler.

Comment: @Awesome i had made a mistake. read it now.

Comment: Too lazy to read the whole post...but get the idea what you wanna do...Good Night.

Comment: You might wanna re-read your second term in RHS. Also e^(i*x/2) is not equal to sqrt(e^(i*x)). But it is fine if they are angles of triangle not it A+B+C=pi. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28e%5E%28i*x%2F2%29%29+-+e%5E%28i*x%2F4%29

Comment: @Awesome the second term was a typo. correcting. and yes, i know that $\sqrt{e^{ix}}\neq e^{ix/2}$ in general. here, anyway while simplifying we'll need $t^2$ not $t$ so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I highly doubt that OP wants to do it with this method.