# If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are the angles of a triangle,....

Tags: trigonometry

If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are the angles of a triangle, prove that:

$$sin\frac {A}{2}+sin\frac {B}{2}+sin\frac {C}{2}=1+4sin\frac {B+C}{4}.sin\frac {C+A}{4}.sin\frac {A+B}{4}$$

My attempt;

Here,
$$A+B+C=\pi$$

Now,

$$L.H.S=sin\frac {A}{2}+sin\frac {B}{2}+sin\frac {C}{2}$$
$$= 2sin\frac {\frac {A}{2}+\frac {B}{2}}{2}.cos\frac {\frac {A}{2}-\frac {B}{2}}+sin\frac {C}{2}$$
$$=2sin\frac {A+B}{4}.cos\frac {A-B}{4}+sin\frac {C}{2}$$
$$=2sin\frac {\pi-C}{4}.cos\frac {A-B}{4}+sin\frac {C}{2}$$

Now, from here I could not.continue, please help me to.complete the proof..

Comment: Duplicat (in particular) of (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/727852)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from your second last step:

$2\sin{\dfrac {A+B}{4}}\cos{\dfrac {A-B}{4}}+\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}}$

$2\sin{\dfrac {A+B}{4}}\cos{\dfrac {A-B}{4}}+\sin{\dfrac{\pi-(A+B)}{2}}$

$2\sin{\dfrac {A+B}{4}}\cos{\dfrac {A-B}{4}}+\cos{\dfrac{A+B}{2}}$

$2\sin{\dfrac {A+B}{4}}\cos{\dfrac {A-B}{4}}+1-2\sin^2{\dfrac{A+B}{4}}$

$1+2\sin{\dfrac {A+B}{4}}(\cos{\dfrac {A-B}{4}}-\sin{\dfrac {A+B}{4}})$

$1+2\sin{\dfrac {A+B}{4}}(\cos{\dfrac {A-B}{4}}-\sin{\dfrac {\pi-C}{4}})$

$1+2\sin{\dfrac {A+B}{4}}(\cos{\dfrac {A-B}{4}}-\cos{\dfrac {\pi+C}{4}})$

$1+2\sin{\dfrac {A+B}{4}}(2\sin{\dfrac{A-B+\pi+C}{8}}\sin{\dfrac{\pi+C-A+B}{8}})$

$1+2\sin{\dfrac {A+B}{4}}(2\sin{\dfrac{2A+2C}{8}}\sin{\dfrac{2B+2C}{8}})$

$1+4\sin{\dfrac {A+B}{4}}\sin{\dfrac{A+C}{4}}\sin{\dfrac{B+C}{4}}$

Comment: ,Thanks a lot. Its simple and clear, too.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

I suggest using the following identities on the RHS of the initial problem:

$$2\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta) = \cos(\alpha - \beta) - \cos(\alpha+\beta)$$

$$2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) = \sin(\alpha + \beta) + \sin(\alpha-\beta)$$

$$2\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta) = \sin(\alpha + \beta) - \sin(\alpha-\beta)$$